# How to edit ntfs metafiles with linux?

Tags: linux, ntfs, ntfs4dos

Several years ago, they were a now discontinued tsr program called ntfs4dos that offered access to Windows® xp/nt drives.
Not only it did provide ntfs access, but ntfs meta files were exposed as regular files so you could do things like :

```
C:\del F:\$LogFile
C:\edit.com F:\$MFTMirr
```

I know about ntfs‑3g and ntfsprogs, but they only provide read only access to meta files even when root.

So how to access such drives under a bash shell and without editing the whole device ?
Especially modern ones that are too large to be mounted by ntfs4dos ?

Comment: “they only provide read only access even when root” To avoid confusion, you might want to specify that this applies only to metadata files, not all files.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto : done.